# Is there a faster way to get UNION ALL behavior in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, performance, union

I have a table (t0), in my Postgres DB, with data that looks something like this:

```
t1_id  t2_id
1      1      
2      1
2      1
4      null
4      null
5      null
```

And I have a query to return my desired results of:

```
t1_id  t2_id
1      1
4      null
5      null
```

My query looks something like this:

```
(
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (t2_id) t1_id, t2_id
  FROM t0
  WHERE t2_id IS NOT NULL
)
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (t1_id) t1_id, t2_id
  FROM t0
  WHERE t2_id IS NULL
)
```

Is there a faster way to do an operation like this? It's not too bad, but I'm doing it in several places (with joins) and all these repeated queries seems to slow stuff down a bit. Seems like there must be a better way.

Here's the query in fiddle form: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/3603

Comment: I don't see a reason for the `union all`: `select distinct on (t2_id) t1_id, t2_id from t0` will do just fine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/3591 Btw. the parentheses around the individual selects are totally useless for the union

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for the response. Nice catch. My example data, and output, we're missing a row.

I updated the question by adding another row `5  null` to the data and query result.

Comment: @Sam: That doesn't change anything. You example is trivial and does not need `UNION ALL`. It needs `ORDER BY` for the `DISTINCT ON` to have determinate results but that's irreleveant. Try adding a query you have and not strip it too much.

Comment: @ypercube, good point. The problem is I want the query here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/3592, to include `5, null`. It combines `4 null` and `5 null` which I want to keep separate.

Comment: Cross post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26344612/is-there-a-faster-way-to-get-union-all-behavior-in-postgres/26344836#26344836

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the simple case, I can only think of minor improvements to the query:

```
(
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (t2_id)
         t1_id, t2_id
  FROM   t0
  WHERE  t2_id IS NOT NULL
  ORDER  BY t2_id, t1_id  -- to get consistent results
)
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (t1_id)
         t1_id, NULL      -- cheaper
  FROM   t0
  WHERE  t2_id IS NULL
  -- if you retrieve more columns, add ORDER BY, too
)
```

- As [ypercube mentioned](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/79980/is-there-a-faster-way-to-get-union-all-behavior-in-postgres#comment144285_79980) You need to add `ORDER BY` with an unambiguous list of expressions to get deterministic results.
- You can use the constant `NULL` instead of `t2_id` in the second leg of the query. Also relevant for below index support.
- The key to performance is **indexing**. Try two **partial indexes** matching the two parts of the query:

  ```
  CREATE INDEX t0_part1_idx ON t0 (t2_id, t1_id) WHERE t2_id IS NOT NULL;
  CREATE INDEX t0_part2_idx ON t0 (t1_id)        WHERE t2_id IS NULL;
  ```

  You may or may not want to include additional columns to allow [index-only scans](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans).

Depending on table size and data distribution, **there may be faster alternatives**:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564) (last chapter)
- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25536748/939860)

#### Single `SELECT`

If you want to condense it into a single `SELECT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (coalesce(t2_id, t1_id), t2_id)
       t1_id, t2_id
FROM   t0
ORDER  BY coalesce(t2_id, t1_id), t2_id, t1_id;
```

Equivalent, except for sort order. If you want this to be fast, try a functional index:

```
CREATE INDEX t0_func_idx ON t0 (coalesce(t2_id, t1_id), t2_id, t1_id);
```

Answer (score 4):

Give your example, this will do it:

```
select distinct on (coalesce(t2_id, t1_id)) t1_id, t2_id
from t0
order by coalesce(t2_id, t1_id);
```

It essentially says "*do a distinct on `t2_id`, but if that is `null` use `t1_id` instead*".

Comment: Thanks! That's perfect! Can't believe I couldn't find that.

Comment: @Sam: That's actually not correct. Consider these corner cases: `(3,3)`, `(3,NULL)` or `(null,7), (7,null)`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4db1b8/1. The test case in the question does not reveal it.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: good catch. But based on the sample data I assumed `t1_id` would never be null

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Might be the case, but would still leave the first example: `(3,3), (3,NULL)`. The 2nd case is just to show why a simple constraint `CHECK (t1_id <> t2_id)` would still not make it right - only in combination with a NOT NULL constraint on `t1_id` ...