# How to order some rows one way, and the rest another way?

Tags: postgresql, order-by, postgresql-10, union

I am trying to sort rows from a table in PostgreSQL 10.12:

```sql
CREATE TABLE example (
 id  serial PRIMARY KEY,
 val text NOT NULL,
 x   integer NOT NULL,
 y   integer NOT NULL
);
    
INSERT INTO example (val,x,y)
VALUES
  ('First Value (This should be first order)',7,2)
, ('Second Value (This should be second order)',6,3)
, ('Third Value (This should be third order)',5,4)
, ('Seventh Value (And This should be last order)',4,1)
, ('Sixth Value (This should be sixth order)',3,5)
, ('Fifth Value (This should be fifth order)',2,6)
, ('Fourth Value (This should be fourth order)',1,7)
;
```

First three result rows should be ordered by `x desc`, and the rest should be ordered by `y desc`.

I tried this query but it is ordering only by `y`:

```
SELECT * from (SELECT * from example order by x desc fetch first 3 rows only) foo
UNION
SELECT * from example order by y desc;
```

But it sorts by only `y`. And I need to get the result without `UNION`.

[Here is an SqlFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/36bc4a/1)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Thank you for the comment. Actually I couldn't explain the question well enough. I have updated it. I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns the top 3 rows according to `ORDER BY x DESC` and appends the rest sorted by `y DESC`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (TABLE example ORDER BY x DESC LIMIT 3)
TABLE cte
UNION ALL
(  -- parentheses required
SELECT e.*
FROM   example e
LEFT   JOIN cte USING (id)
WHERE  cte.id IS NULL
ORDER  BY e.y DESC
);
```

`TABLE` is just shorthand for `SELECT * FROM`.

`UNION ALL` makes sure that the two derived tables are just appended without trying to eliminate (non-existent) duplicates and thereby messing with the sort order.

Parentheses are required so that `ORDER BY` only applies enclosed `SELECT`, not to the complete set of rows.

See:

- [Combine multiple SELECT statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11833128/939860)
- [Is order preserved after UNION in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31976967/939860)

Related:

- [Combining 2 SELECT queries and printing the results in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/131231/combining-2-select-queries-and-printing-the-results-in-postgresql/131251#131251)
- [Is there a faster way to get UNION ALL behavior in Postgres?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/79980/is-there-a-faster-way-to-get-union-all-behavior-in-postgres/80605#80605)

#### Without `UNION`

```sql
SELECT e.*
FROM   example  e
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT id, x FROM example ORDER BY x DESC LIMIT 3
   ) c USING (id)
ORDER  BY c.x DESC NULLS LAST, e.y DESC;
```

Same result.

The `LEFT JOIN` results in `c.x` being `NULL` except for the top 3 chosen rows. So the first `ORDER BY` items `c.x DESC NULLS LAST` only sorts the first 3 rows and leaves the rest unsorted. The second `ORDER BY` item `e.y DESC` sorts the rest as desired.

About `NULLS LAST`:

- [Sort by column ASC, but NULL values first?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9511492/939860)

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=63a9608c7684af673efab5db1938897a)*

If the table is not trivially small, you should have and index on `(x)` and another one on `(y)`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually I think I couldn't explain well enough the question. So I updated the question

Comment: Can we get the same result without union ?

Comment: @OğuzCanSertel: Yes, I have a nice one.

Comment: Both of are perfect and very educated answers for me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a common table expression:

```
with    cte_example
            as
            (
                select row_number() over (order by x desc) as my_row_count
                , id, val, x, y
                from example
            )   
            select my_row_count, id, val, x, y
            from cte_example
            where my_row_count <= 3;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually I think I couldn't explain well enough the question. So I updated the question